# Pusher - Ping pong functionality

Tags: pusher

I see that Pusher supports ping pong based on the [docs](http://pusher.com/docs/pusher_protocol#ping-pong).

However, I am not sure on where to start on this.

What I want to do is check [half open connections](http://pusher.tenderapp.com/kb/faq-common-requests/half-open-connections-lead-to-temporarily-incorrect-connection-counts-and-webhook-call-delays) and close them because I am getting an unrealistic number of concurrent connections on my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ping and pong are part of the [WebSocket protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-37) but aren't implemented by web browsers yet (that I know of). So, Pusher has added their own Ping and Pong messages to the [Pusher WebSocket Protocol](http://pusher.com/docs/pusher_protocol), that you've referenced.

If you are using version 1.11 or above of the Pusher JavaScript library then the library will be sending and receiving ping/pong messages. Even with those messages it is still possible to see half-open TCP connections. And it can take some time for those connections to be detected using the ping/pong strategy; as the [FAQ](http://web.archive.org/web/20140720070504/http://pusher.tenderapp.com:80/kb/faq-common-requests/half-open-connections-lead-to-temporarily-incorrect-connection-counts-and-webhook-call-delays) says, 360 seconds.